# The code isn't working for some reason

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm making a thingy that takes 3 inputs like "1500, 1 and 1" or "1500, January and 1" and returns "January 1st, 1500" or "1/1/1500", i had some problems on the day part but someone already told me how to fix it, and now I'm having problems with the month part, i made this kinda fast and i haven't figured out why it isn't working, it SHOULD see if the input is a valid month, if it is then it outputs the month(this part is just for testing), and if it isn't then it should say "please use a valid month or a number between 1 and 12", but when i write anything that isn't a month it just stops, and doesn't output anything, even if i put a month after it just doesn't do anything, i tried to see if there was any errors but i didn't found any, this is the code that i used:

```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   String mx;
   System.out.println("Insert Month");
   String[] mm = {"january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"};
   int mz = 0;
   while (0 < 1){
   mx = scan.nextLine();
       mx = mx.toLowerCase();
       for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
           if (mx.equals(mm[i])){
               mz = i + 1;
               break;
           }
           else {
               if(i == 11){
                   System.out.println("please use a valid month or a number between 1 and 12");
               }
               else{
               }
           }
       } 
   //}
   if(mz > 0){
       break;
   }
   else {}
   }
   System.out.println(mx);
```

Comment: There are 12 months in a year, so you should check to i < 12, not 11.

Comment: why the sporadic input? Why not ask them to enter a month first, then a day, and then a year. You should restrict the user's input to make your life easier

Comment: Just make your for loop this way `for(int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)`

Comment: that worked, it ended up that it was something dumb that made it not work, just as i thought XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your program just "stops" is that you only print the statement "please enter a valid month..." if `i == 11` and you have your `for` loop break if `i >= 11`. Thus, this condition will never be met. The while loop keeps running, even though this statement isnt printed. You could have entered a non-month string on the first try, and then a month string on the second and your while loop would have been broken.

Here is how I have improved your code to work for taking in the month. Pay attention to subtle changes of highlighted. These are important for writing better, more readable code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
//initialize to empty string
String mx = "";
System.out.println("Insert Month");
//use good naming conventions for easier code readability
String[] validMonths = {"january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"};
//using a boolean to break makes much more sense than the way you have written it with an infinite loop and a manual break statement
boolean noMonth = true;
while (noMonth){
    mx = scan.nextLine();
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        //rather than convert to lowercase, use this handy String method
        //also compares for valid number entries
        if (mx.equalsIgnoreCase(validMonths[i]) || mx.equals(Integer.toString(i+1))){
             noMonth = false;
             break;
        }
    }
    if(noMonth){
        System.out.println("please use a valid month or a number between 1 and 12");
    }
}
System.out.println(mx);
```

Create a new while loop to take in the day and a new one to take in the year after these, checking for valid input. Also, every if does not require an else in Java.

Comment: Will it work for `december`?

Comment: didn't see that error in the OP's code. good call

Answer (score 0):

You're not using meaningful variable names, making your code a little bit hard to read and maintain. So, I had to create you the following code from scratch:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String month = getMonthName(getInt("Enter Month: ", keyboard) - 1);
        int day = getInt("Enter Day: ", keyboard);
        int year = getInt("Enter Year: ", keyboard);

        System.out.printf("%s %d, %d\n", month, day, year);

}

public static String getMonthName(final int monthNo)
{
       String[] months = {"january","february","march","april","may","june","july","august","september","october","november","december"};
       return months[monthNo];
} 


public static int getInt(final String msg, Scanner keyboard)
{
        System.out.print(msg);
        return keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

The code above does NOT perform and input validation, as you may have noticed already. If you want to validate month input for example, your if condition may look something like this:

```
if (month < 0 || month < 12)
{
 System.out.println("Invalid month number entered");      
 System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You need to handle input errors. nextInt throws an error if the input is not an int

Comment: Like I said in my last edit, the code does NOT perform any input validation. He seems to have a hard time figuring out the logic of his program, not writing the code. Of course if he needs to handle every possible error, a try-catch statement will do (which I would personally highly discourage).